# Understanding the definition of monotone class

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

It looks like a trivial question but I'm having difficulty in understanding the definition of monotone class, which is defined by

> Monotone class on space X is a subset $\mathcal{C}$ of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ that is closed under countable increasing union and countable decreasing intersection. That is,
>
> $E_j \in \mathcal{C}$ for $j\in\mathbb{N}$ and $E_1\subset E_2\subset ... \Rightarrow \bigcup_{1}^{\infty} E_j \in \mathcal{C}$
>
> $E_j \in \mathcal{C}$ for $j\in\mathbb{N}$ and $E_1\supset E_2\supset ... \Rightarrow \bigcap_{1}^{\infty} E_j \in \mathcal{C}$

My confusion is, since $E_1\subset E_2\subset ...$, isn't $\bigcup_{1}^{\infty} E_j = \lim_{j\to\infty}E_j$, which is assumed to be in $\mathcal{C}$ already?

Likewise, if $E_1\supset E_2\supset ...$, then $\bigcap_{1}^{\infty} E_j = \lim_{j\to\infty}E_j \in \mathcal{C}$ trivially. If so, then every set that satisfies the assumptions are a monotone class, which makes the definition meaningless.

I must have misunderstood something. Can one point it out for me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is a limit of sets, and why do you assume that your class is closed under these "limits"?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The "limit" of sets is in the same sense as the "limit" when we write $\{E_j\}_1^{\infty}$. Since $\{E_j\}_1^{\infty} \subset \mathcal{A}$, $E_j \in \mathcal{A}$ for any $j\in\mathbb{N}$, so if the sequence is increasing, the very large $E_j$ when $j\to\infty$ (here I denote it as $\lim_{j\to\infty} E_j$) is equal to  $\bigcap_{1}^{\infty} E_j$, right? Since the very large $E_j$ is in $\mathcal{A}$, I obtain $\bigcap_{1}^{\infty} E_j$ ...

Comment: No, when you write $\{E_j\}_1^{\infty}$, there is no "limit." You are not defining things, you are imagining them. There is no "limit". Try doing a proper, clear definition, and you will see what you have is nothing. You are also wrong here. Say $E_j=\{1,2,\ldots,j\}$. The family $\{E_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ contains only finite sets, but $\cup_1^{\infty}E_j$ is infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sets $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i$ and $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty E_i$ aren't really limits.
They are defined as $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i = \{x \mid \exists i \in \mathbb{N}: x \in E_i\}$ and $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty = \{x \mid \forall i \in \mathbb{N}: x \in E_i\}$. In particular some $\mathcal{S} \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ doesn't need to include these, for example let $X= \mathbb{R}$    and take the set of all closed intervals as $\mathcal{S}$.
Them, for $E_i := [-i,i]$ we clearly have $E_1 \subset E_2 \subset \ldots$ and $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i = \mathbb{R}$ since for every
$x \in \mathbb{R}$ there is an $i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \in [i,i]$. But $\mathbb{R}\notin \mathcal{S}$ .
Simirlarly with $\mathcal{S}'$ as the set of all open intervals and $E_i = (\frac{-1}{i}, \frac{1}{i})$ we have $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty E_i = \{0\}$

Comment: Thanks! It really clarifies!